# Savebox and usebox unexpected behaviour for the box with index 10

Tags: boxes

I have found that when saving and later using boxes the box with index 10 behaves differently to all other.

Here is simple demo that shows different behaviour. In preamble I define this commands:

```
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{BoxCount}
\newcommand{\numberedBox}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \savebox{\theBoxCount}{\vbox{\noindent\theBoxCount\\~ #1}}%
}%
\newcommand{\writeBoxes}{
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \newcounter{I}%
  \setcounter{I}{1}%
  \forloop{I}{1}{\value{I} < \value{BoxCount}}{%
  \usebox{\theI}\par
}%
```

The `\numbredBox` basically stores given text in indexed box while adding number of the box to the text. The `\writeBoxes` prints all stored boxes in order they were stored.

In document body I have this code:

```
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\numberedBox{word}
\writeBoxes
```

This is printed output of this document:
[image]
All the boxes are printed as expected except for 10th box which somehow interfere with box 11. I have played with similar code a little and found out that 10th saved almost always box behaves strange. In some cases I even got `! Incompatible list can't be unboxed` error but only for 10th saved box (content of all the boxes was equal).

Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

---

### EDIT

Here is complete source of this example that Hebert asked for. Just compile with pdfLaTeX and you will get output shown above.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{BoxCount}
\newcommand{\numberedBox}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \savebox{\theBoxCount}{\vbox{\noindent\theBoxCount\\~ #1}}%
}%
\newcommand{\writeBoxes}{
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \newcounter{I}%
  \setcounter{I}{1}%
  \forloop{I}{1}{\value{I} < \value{BoxCount}}{%
    \usebox{\theI}\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \writeBoxes
\end{document}
```

Comment: give a _complete_ example.

Comment: @Herbert The code that was there was almost complete - except for document class, begin and end of the document. Nevertheless I have added complete source, please see my edit.

Comment: no, I couldn't see how you define the boxes

Comment: @Herbert I just use numbers as their names and so I don't need to define them. I take it (from egreg's answer) that I'm in the fact using Tex registers for storing boxes.

Comment: As Herbert says, your code doesn't declare the boxes - there is no `\newsavebox`.  Also, if add a `\tracingassigns=1`, or just `\showbox11`, you will see that `\box11` is not void when you define it, so it is being used by something else.

Comment: Why do you need boxes? Perhaps also macros would do the job (and perhaps even better)?

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek I use boxes because they allow me to measure their width and height. Macros would not allow that.

Comment: `\settowidth` and `\settoheight` do not need explicit boxes. Or one local box for measurement can be used.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek I measure actual width and height I do not set it. As to your second suggestion, yes I could use macros and one local box for measurement. But what would I gain? Boxes as suggested in  Herbert's answer seems to be doing the job...

Comment: I do not know the concrete application of the box measurement stuff. But using a different box register each time without reusing the contents several times in the whole document seems not the best choice to me. Perhaps you can make your application more clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use the LaTeX definition of boxes:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{BoxCount}
\setcounter{BoxCount}{0}
\newcounter{I}
\newcommand\numberedBox[1]{%
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \expandafter\newsavebox\expandafter{\csname BOX\alph{BoxCount}\endcsname}
  \expandafter\sbox\expandafter{\csname BOX\alph{BoxCount}\endcsname}{\vbox{\noindent\theBoxCount\\~ #1}}%
}%
\newcommand{\writeBoxes}{
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \setcounter{I}{1}%
  \forloop{I}{1}{\value{I} < \value{BoxCount}}{%
    \usebox{\csname BOX\alph{I}\endcsname}\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \writeBoxes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

You shouldn't be using box registers by number other than those numbered from 0 to 9.

In particular box register 10 corresponds to `\voidb@x` which the LaTeX kernel considers as an always empty box. If you fill it with something a number of macros will work wrongly. Among them

```
\leavevmode
\settowidth \settoheight \settowidth
```

Why do you get an error? Because `\usebox` does `\leavevmode` which in turn does `\unhbox\voidb@x`; you've set `\box10` (that is `\voidb@x`) to a `\vbox`, so the command performed by `\leavevmode` tries to `\unhbox` a `\vbox`, which is not allowed.

Here's a safer (but not completely foolproof) way. If it's just for experiments, then it's not so risky; on the other hand I would never use this for real document production. In that case I would allocate my box registers.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{forloop,etex}
\newcounter{BoxCount}
\setcounter{BoxCount}{\count14}
\ifnum\value{BoxCount}<256 
  \setcounter{BoxCount}{355}
\else
  \addtocounter{BoxCount}{100}
\fi
\mathchardef\FirstBoxCount=\value{BoxCount}
\newcommand{\numberedBox}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \savebox{\theBoxCount}{\vbox{\noindent\theBoxCount\\~ #1}}%
}
\newcounter{I}
\newcommand{\writeBoxes}{%
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \setcounter{I}{\FirstBoxCount}%
  \forloop{I}{1}{\value{I} < \value{BoxCount}}{%
    \usebox{\theI}\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \writeBoxes
\end{document}
```

Using the extended register set and going 100 registers from the last allocated one if the extended register set is already used, this should work without touching any allocated box register.

---

The LaTeX kernel allocates more box than register 10:

```
\voidb@x=\box10
\strutbox=\box11
\@tempboxa=\box12
\rootbox=\box13
\@labels=\box14
\@curline=\box15
\@curfield=\box16
\@tabfbox=\box17
\@arstrutbox=\box18
\@picbox=\box19
\@linechar=\box20
\@dashbox=\box21
\@begindvibox=\box22
\@outputbox=\box23
\@leftcolumn=\box24
\@holdpg=\box25
```

Using these registers and following ones possibly allocated by packages is an almost sure way to make things go wrong. You're shooting your own foot if you do it.

---

Here is a completely safe version.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{forloop,etex}
\newcounter{BoxCount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myBox}[1]{\@nameuse{myBox@\number\value{#1}}}
\newcommand{\checkBox}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{myBox@\number\value{#1}}
    {\expandafter\newbox\csname myBox@\number\value{#1}\endcsname}
    {}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\numberedBox}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \checkBox{BoxCount}%
  \savebox{\myBox{BoxCount}}{\vbox{\noindent\theBoxCount\\~ #1}}%
}
\newcounter{I}
\newcommand{\writeBoxes}{%
  \stepcounter{BoxCount}%
  \setcounter{I}{1}%
  \forloop{I}{1}{\value{I} < \value{BoxCount}}{%
    \usebox{\myBox{I}}\par
  }%
}
\begin{document}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \numberedBox{word}
  \writeBoxes
\end{document}
```

When you set a box associated to a counter's value, you first check for its allocation:

```
\checkBox{BoxCount}
```

will allocate a new box register if you haven't done it so far; if the box register is already allocated, nothing happens. Then you use

```
\myBox{<counter>}
```

when you need to save or use the box register corresponding to the counter's value.

Comment: +1 So to avoid it I only set initial value of `BoxCount` to 11? If it works, you are the man!

Comment: @drasto Not at all. You're doing damages to other reserved box registers.

Comment: @dastro You should be using a range of boxes you've reserved. Normally, you don't work with box numbers but with names (created using `\newbox`). You could go for something like `\expandafter\newbox\csname mybox@1\endcsname`, _etc._, to give yourself a set of boxes with numbers in the names.

Comment: @Joseph Wright I would like to use box names instead of numbers to not to interfere with Tex registers (I understand now that it is not good practise). Your comment is welcome but it does not show how can I declare box that has name consisting of some letters and value of a counter. I really need to use value of a counter instead of just fixes numbers in boxes names. And I'd like to use LaTeX macro `\newsavebox` instead of Tex `\newbox`. If you can show me how to solve this 2 thinks, please do and make it an answer so I can upvote and even accept it.